# Printable Stylesheet with DIV

Tags: css, html

I have a site that I'm trying to make a printable version and I'm using a new print stylesheet, but I'm having a problem. I have a DIV for star ratings that is just an empty DIV in the html file, but in the regular CSS I have background images for the actual stars.

The DIV in the html file looks like this:

```
<div class="example_rating"></div>
```

The code in the regular stylesheet looks like this:

```
.example_rating {

  height:40px;

  width:200px;

  margin-left:20%;

  background: url('../stars.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;

  }
```

My problem is that the star ratings aren't showing up at all in the printable format of the web page. I don't have the DIV hidden or anything, but I'm not sure what I can do to get it to show up in the printable format.

I realize the question may be a little vague, but I'm not sure how else to explain it. I can definitely give more details if need though. Thanks!

Comment: Is the background image the one that shows the rating and it does not print?

Comment: You can't force backgrounds to be shown. Maybe you want replace it with <img> instead. Or some "*****" thing..

Comment: Yes, it's just not showing up on the print friendly version of the web page. I don't know why though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your CSS, the stars are rendered as a background image, and when printing, backgrounds aren't usually displayed by default.

You'll either have to display the stars as an `<img>`, or tell your users to enable printing of backgrounds.

**EDIT:**

The easiest way to get round this would be to print the star rating as text *as well as* the background image, and then have the font inside the div transparent (and yellow in the print stylesheet). Example:

```
<div class="example_rating">
  4/5 stars.
</div>
```

Stylesheet:

```
.example_rating {
  color:Transparent;
  /* Alternatively: text-indent: -9999px; */
  height:40px;
  width:200px;
  margin-left:20%;
  background: url('../stars.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

You could try putting this in your print stylesheet:

```
.example_rating {
  background: none;
}
.example_rating:after {
  content: '4/5 stars'
}
```

This puts some text inside the div using CSS, and if you put it in your print stylesheet only, it will only appear when you print!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately this is for an assignment and I'm not allowed to edit the HTML file. I'll have to figure out a way to make it work with just CSS, but I'm not sure that's possible :/

Comment: @stephen - See my second edit. It should do what you want (in a hacky way), but it won't work on older versions of internet explorer.

Answer (score -1):

Try making a new print only stylesheet... like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

Or in you current stylesheet, put your printing styles in

```
@media print { 
}
```